# CaptainCasa undecorated popup cant be sizeable

Tags: popup

I am trying to make undecorated popup sizeable.
The method `setSizeableIfUndecorated(true)` seems to not working.
Tested with ModalPopup and ModelessPopup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested with...

```
    ...
    final H70_pdfUI ui = new H70_pdfUI();
    ModelessPopup mp = openModelessPopup(ui,"",300,300,new DefaultModelessPopupListener(this,ui));
    mp.setUndecorated(true);
    mp.setSizeableIfUndecorated(true);
    ...
```

...and saw: the decoartion side areas are available and you can resize - but the cursor is not indicating this by updating its shape. The style is missing in the .css since update 20220314 (due to a generalization of the decoration-style...).

We now added it to the style again, so it will be properly styled with 20220328 (next Monday).

If you want to add the style classes as part of your individual style, then this can be done by adding the style class definitions:

```
    <class n="riscdialognodecoration_edgesizer">
    <style n="background" v="transparent"/>
    <style n="cursor" v="nw-resize"/>
</class>
<class n="riscdialognodecoration_sizer_left">
    <style n="background" v="transparent"/>
    <style n="cursor" v="w-resize"/>
</class>
<class n="riscdialognodecoration_sizer_right">
    <style n="background" v="transparent"/>
    <style n="cursor" v="e-resize"/>
</class>
<class n="riscdialognodecoration_sizer_top">
    <style n="background" v="transparent"/>
    <style n="cursor" v="n-resize"/>
</class>
<class n="riscdialognodecoration_sizer_bottom">
    <style n="background" v="transparent"/>
    <style n="cursor" v="s-resize"/>
</class>
```

Please pay attention: the name of the style classes contain a "no"! And also pleasy pay attention: you should take out these extra-definitions when applying next week's version.